# Copy one column to another, two seperate tables

Tags: mysql

I want to copy all values from one column in table A to another column in table B. The column has 100+ rows. I tried this:

```
UPDATE nds_product_lang pl 
    SET description_short = (
        SELECT product_supplier_reference
          FROM nds_product_supplier ps
         WHERE ps.id_product = pl.id_product);
```

But what it returns is

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

It returns the same error even if I remove the WHERE condition. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE nds_product_lang pl, nds_product_supplier ps
SET pl.description_short = ps.product_supplier_reference 
WHERE ps.id_product = pl.id_product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a store procedure:
See below example

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `additem`()
BEGIN
declare no_record int default 0;
declare mycat varchar(45) default ''; //variable data destination
declare mycursor CURSOR FOR   // this point your source table
select field-name FROM yourtable;
declare continue handler for not found
set no_record = 1;
open mycursor;

add_item: LOOP
 FETCH mycursor INTO mycat;
 IF no_record = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE add_item;
 END IF;
 -- build email list
insert into dest_table values(val-field1,mycat, ect..); 
END LOOP add_item;

close  mycursor;
```

this work perfectly :-)